# Spark sql: How do I filter a dataframe twice and then join together?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to filter and join to do a simple pivot but getting very odd results.

```
val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)
import sqlContext.implicits._

val people = Array((1, "sam"), (2, "joe"), (3, "sally"), (4, "joanna"))
val accounts = Array(
  (1, "checking", 100.0),
  (1, "savings", 300.0),
  (2, "savings", 1000.0),
  (3, "carloan", 12000.0),
  (3, "checking", 400.0)
)

val t1 = sc.makeRDD(people).toDF("uid", "name")
val t2 = sc.makeRDD(accounts).toDF("uid", "type", "amount")

val t2c = t2.filter(t2("type") <=> "checking")
val t2s = t2.filter(t2("type") <=> "savings")

t1.
  join(t2c, t1("uid") <=> t2c("uid"), "left").
  join(t2s, t1("uid") <=> t2s("uid"), "left").
  take(10)
```

The results are wrong:

```
Array(
  [1,sam,1,checking,100.0,1,savings,300.0],
  [1,sam,1,checking,100.0,2,savings,1000.0],
  [2,joe,null,null,null,null,null,null],
  [3,sally,3,checking,400.0,1,savings,300.0],
  [3,sally,3,checking,400.0,2,savings,1000.0],
  [4,joanna,null,null,null,null,null,null]
)
```

The way I can force it to work properly is to create a new df for each filter:

```
val t2a = sc.makeRDD(accounts).toDF("uid", "type", "amount")
val t2s = t2a.filter(t2a("type") <=> "savings")

t1.
  join(t2c, t1("uid") <=> t2c("uid"), "left").
  join(t2s, t1("uid") <=> t2s("uid"), "left").
  take(10)
```

The results are right:

```
Array(
  [1,sam,1,checking,100.0,1,savings,300.0],
  [2,joe,null,null,null,2,savings,1000.0],
  [3,sally,3,checking,400.0,null,null,null],
  [4,joanna,null,null,null,null,null,null]
)
```

This solution isn't workable so is there a better way?

Comment: would you care to explain what do you mean by the solution isn't workable ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I filed this as a bug:
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-15063

The resolution is there's an alternate way of performing the join:

```
   t1.
     join(t2c, Seq("uid"), "left").
     join(t2s, Seq("uid"), "left").
     take(10)
```

There may be a bug that is not allowing the original form to work.